# NullPointerException while trying to startActivityForResult

Tags: android

Edit: the answer is not to call `startActivityForResult` on the called Activity object, instead invoke it from the caller's context.

This is my code, exception on last line:

```
107 Intent intent = new Intent(CallingActivity.this, CalledActivity.class);
108 CalledActivity calledActivity = new CalledActivity();
109 calledActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, CALLED_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

Inside CallingActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(SR.tag,"req=" + requestCode + " res=" + resultCode); //Never getting here
}
```

Manifest file snippet:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.CallingActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ui.CalledActivity"></activity>
```

Exception:

```
01-14 11:30:14.850: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 11:30:14.850: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1036): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 11:30:14.850: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1036):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2833)
01-14 11:30:14.850: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1036):     at com.litvin.app.ui.CallingActivity.onSharedPreferenceChanged(CallingActivity.java:109    )
...
```

Whenever I move the HOME and LAUNCHER intent filters into `.ui.CalledActivity`, it works fine. It starts CalledActivity when I press the icon.

I have looked through many similar answers here, but none worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// no need to create any object for that

```
CalledActivity calledActivity = new CalledActivity(); //comment this line
```

//do this

```
intent.startActivityForResult(intent, CALLED_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

Comment: So bloody simple yet so much time wasted.. Thanks :)

Comment: Your code would throw a compile error: "The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Intent"

Answer (score 1):

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(CallingActivity.this, CalledActivity.class);
      startActivityForResult(intent, CALLED_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

Comment: indeed, it should be invoked on the caller's context and not on the intent object.